# OpenCL: multiple clEnqueueNDRangeKernel() calls

Tags: opencl

I'm confused about how clEnqueueNDRangeKernel() works when called multiple times.  Let's say I enqueue 10 times (for example, with a for loop), each time with global_work_size = 32.  Let's say the kernel takes a global argument that it populates with get_global_id(0).

My question is about the enumeration of the global_id's.

What I expected:
The highest-numbered global_id would be (10*32-1)=319.

What actually happens:
The highest-numbered global_id is (32-1)=31.

Can anyone explain how each work item is enumerated, step-by-step, as multiple clEnqueueNDRangeKernel() calls are made?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The NDRange space created in each clEnqueueNDRAngeKernel call is independent of each other, the global work item IDs is not consecutive or related at all between each call.